# Does select(NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout) just wait the given time?

Tags: c++, linux

the following line has come to my eyes in given code:

```
select(0, (fd_set *) NULL, (fd_set *) NULL, (fd_set *) NULL, &timeout);
```

http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

> Each of the three file descriptor sets may be specified as NULL if no
>   file descriptors are to be watched for the corresponding class of
>   events.

So I can see that it is valid to pass NULL into it. In that case it can only lead to do active waiting.

Is this correct? I am a bit unsure..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a
>   non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond
>   precision.

Taken from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).